# promise with loop and file read in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, formidable

I looked at lot of example but couldn't achieve it..so need help..

**Problem..**

1. the content from loop should be passed to execute one by one.
2. each loop iteration contains a file read and database save operation along with few other object properties that need to be assigned.

**I have created example here..**

http://runnable.com/VI1efZDJvlQ75mlW/api-promise-loop-for-node-js-and-hello-world

**how to run:**

Api: http://web-91b5a8f5-67af-4ffd-9a32-54a50b10fce3.runnable.com/api/upload

method : POST

content-type : multipart/form-data

upload more than one file with name.

..

**the final expected promise is**

```
files.name = "name of file"
files.content
files.content-type
files.size
```

- saved to db.

currently i am getting different content from file..but other files content are not filled and is undefined.

Regards
Moyeen

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code in your question?

Comment: @Bergi the code is in the link..

Comment: Well, [that just the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code). See also [this FAQ entry](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1048572)

Comment: And now, of course, runnable has been bought out and whatever is at your URL is 1GB and doesn't seem to be javascript code.  Case in point for what @Bergi was saying!

Answer (score 4):

The technique you're looking for is thenable chaining

```
var p= Q();
Object.keys(files).forEach(function(key){
  p = p.then(function(){ // chain the next one
    return Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, files[key].path, "binary", i). // readfile
      then(function (content) { // process content and save
        files.filename =  files[key].name;
        files.path = files[key].path;
        files.content_type = files[key].type;
        files.size = files[key].size;
        console.log(files.filename);
        files.content = binaryToBase64(content);
        return Q.npost(art.save, art); // wait for save, update as needed
    }));
  });
});
```

Basically, we tell each operation to happen after the previous one has finished by chaining them and `return`ing which causes a wait on the asynchronous value.

As a byproduct you can later use

```
p.then(function(last){
    // all done, access last here
});
```

The handler will run when all the promises are done.

Comment: Why not use `reduce`?

Comment: @Bergi note that `files` is an object and I'm iterating its keys here so the edit is incorrect. I would use `.reduce` in my own code but generally I find that people understand it a lot less in stack overflow and making them learn two things at once (promises and reduce) sounds like overkill.

Comment: i cant vote up as i dont have reputations to vote..:(

Comment: @Bergi Don't worry about it I've done it to you at least once/twice before :P

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code with Q.all as the mentioned p.then will execute only once.

http://runnable.com/VI1efZDJvlQ75mlW/api-promise-loop-for-node-js-and-hello-world

```
 form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    var p = Q();
    Object.keys(files).forEach(function (key) {
        promises.push(p.then(function () { // chain the next one
            return Q.nfcall(fs.readFile, files[key].path, "binary"). // readfile
                then(function (content) { // process content and save
                   file = {};
                    file.filename = files[key].name;
                    file.path = files[key].path;
                    file.content_type = files[key].type;
                    file.size = files[key].size;
                    console.log(files[key].name);
                    file.content = binaryToBase64(content);
                    filesarr.push(file);
                   // Q.npost(art.save, art); // wait for save, update as needed
                })
        }));

        Q.all(promises);
    });
});
```

the question is how to use q.npost if i have mongoose model files and want to save...?

Comment: Check my answer with the `return` of the `npost`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I tried that return..but it didnt post...just got output in logs...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I did following changes it updated thansk.. "Q.npost(files,"save"); // wait for save, update as needed