# Using deferred promise inside for each loop using node.js

Tags: node.js, promise, cheerio

I am running into an issue when I use promise inside a loop in node.js.
Below is a simple example, I am using cheerio to scrape a web page and do the following:

```
$('.xyz').each(function(){
  fn1()
  .then(fn2)
  .then(fn3)    
});


function fn1() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  console.log("1");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}

function fn2() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  console.log("2");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}

function fn3() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  console.log("3");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

I was expecting the final output to be 123123123, but instead I am getting 111222333. Could someone explain why this is happening. I am pretty new to node.js and could use some help.

Comment: Here is an example on how to do it with thenable chaining: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27468188/1348195 I can add an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `Q` schedules "then" callback to the next tick (after the promise was resolved). See [source](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L816). "Next tick" in turn is realized through `setImmediate` or  `setTimeout` or `process.nextTick` and so on, depending on the platform you are using (see [source](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L147)). All promises realization guarantees that `then` callback will be executed after current call stack execution. It can be realized through adding callback to the microtask queue (like v8 engine) or to the event loop task queue (using `setTimeout` for example). If you do not understand how event loop task queue works - see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: Thanks! That video helped. I resolved the issue by following suggestions from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217736/while-loop-with-promises?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There's a subtle difference between queueing up a promise handler and redeclaring the promise. Consider the following code, which produces the behaviour you desire, that is, 123123123:

```
var a = Q();

[1,2,3].forEach(function(){
  a = a.then(fn1)
    .then(fn2)
    .then(fn3);
});


function fn1() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  console.log("1");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}

function fn2() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  console.log("2");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}

function fn3() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  console.log("3");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

(JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/hituzedare/2/edit?js,console)

Now consider the following, very similar example, which results in 111222333.

```
var a = Q();

[1,2,3].forEach(function(){
  a.then(fn1)
    .then(fn2)
    .then(fn3);
});


function fn1() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  console.log("1");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}

function fn2() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  console.log("2");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}

function fn3() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  console.log("3");
  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

(JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/hituzedare/1/edit?js,console)

The catch is: the first example redefines the variable as a new promise - specifically, the promise returned by `fn3`.

Therefore, on the next `forEach` iteration, the promise is now chained to the end of `fn3`, not to the top promise.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's true that you're chaining your promises with groups of threes, but you're running each chain parallelly, so the flow goes something like:

1. Run `fn1()`, schedule `fn2` and `fn3` for later.
2. Run `fn1()` again, schedule the same
3. Run `fn1()` yet again, schedule the same
4. One of the `fn2()`s run
5. etc...

If you want them to run sequentially, you need to schedule them all on the same promise object.