# javascript promise in loop or how to call function one-by-one

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, promise

I work with slimerjs. So I have an array with urls and function (foo) that makes something with one url. This function return Promise.

It's ok if I do somth like this:

```
 foo(urls).then(foo, orError).then(foo, orError).....
```

But I want to call foo() in loop, so I try this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++ ) { foo(urls).then(foo, error); }
```

But it doesnt work.

Maybe I dont need promises here, i dunno.

How can I call async function in loop, but wait until function finish?

Here's my "foo" function:

```
function visitPage(urls) {
    return new Promise(function(success, error) {
        var url = urls.shift();
        if (!url) error();
        logger.log("Opening " + url);
        page
            .open(url)
            .then(function(status) {
                if (status !== "success") error();
                return page.evaluate(function() {
                    return document.body.innerHTML;
                });
            }).then(function(body) {
                var founded = looker.lookForAlpari(body);
                logger.log(founded);
                page.close();
                success(urls);
            });
    });
}
```

and here's my loop

```
for ( var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++ ) {
    visitPage(urls)
      .then(visitPage, showError);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just visiting the URLs asynchronously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27469072/1348195) the technique is to chain the actions themselves, either by an actual for loop or by a `.reduce`. Since you asked for a for loop let's stick to that:

```
var queue = Promise.resolve(); // start waiting
urls.forEach(function(url){
     queue = queue.then(function(result){
        // put result somewhere
        return visitPage(url);
    });
});
queue.then(function(){
     // all done here
});
```

You can change `visitPage` to only take a url rather than mutate urls which should be nicer anyway.

Comment: Won't `queue` be equal to the last `Promise` returned from the loop? What do you mean when in the comment you say `all done here`.

Comment: @SuhailGupta yes it will be, what he means is once the function you pass to the last then block is called it means all the urls have already been hit in a serial fashion. As an addition you can add a catch block to handle errors.