# Call function when the last one has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sure it looks like this question has been asked a lot before, but it's not the typical async JS question "how to call a function only when another one has finished?".

So my scenario is the following: I need to load a pretty heavy set of data with AJAX, a list of matches arranged in the weeks where they're played. I set up an array of promises and when they're all done I do something else once I have all the matches in the DOM. I had something like this:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 1; var i <= lastWeek; i++)
  promises.push($.ajax({
    url: "week/" + i,
    success: { ... }
  }));

$.when.apply($, promises).done(someFunction);
```

However I noticed this would fire all requests at once and could clog the process in the server side and malfunction in general. So I figured I would approach this differently, instead of making all those requests at once I make one for the first week, and once that one's done, I make the following, and so on:

```
function loadWeek(week, last) {
  $.get("week/" + i, function (response) {
    // do whatever with the response
    // make the request for the next week
    if (week + 1 <= last)
      loadWeek(week + 1, last);
  });
}
```

Now of course I cannot use `$.when` because the promises are generated on the fly as the previous one is completed.

I wonder if there is a way JS or jQuery offers to signal the `someFunction` function (the one that should be called only after all matches have been loaded) after the last week has been loaded.

Of course, you could say, just call it when `week + 1 > last` right? Well, I still need to work with promises because this `someFunction` not only needs to wait for these matches to be loaded but also for another promise to complete.

So you could say I lied a little when I said I was doing this:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).done(someFunction);
```

When in reality, `promises` actually have more function calls other than the list of matches, and `someFunction` should have until **all** of them have finished.

Comment: Maybe jQuery `.finish(function(){ //do somthing... });` ?

Comment: how do you know, when all of them finished? I mean, what is the criteria? A specific length?

Comment: @Syntac what do you mean with "all"? if you're talking about the list of matches, well, that one's finished when `week` is greater than `last` and we're in the `success` block. As of the other ones, we know they have finished because it's a promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript promise in loop or how to call function one-by-one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28851578/javascript-promise-in-loop-or-how-to-call-function-one-by-one)

Comment: side query: if the original version sent all requests at once and clogged the server was this due to a resource limitation on the server? and if so, do you expect multiple users in the future who will still have the ability to clog things up even if you did get the requests from a single user to fire one at a time?

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ku0vpbos/) with the code from the possible duplicate

Comment: @Andreas yeah I checked out the duplicate but I can't see how I might work that solution into my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so lets break this down, if I understood you correctly you want the following

**A- Load weeks sequentially**

```
function loadWeek(week, last) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    (function request(week, last) {
        $.get("week/" + i, function (response) {
            // do whatever with the response
            // make the request for the next week
            if (week + 1 <= last)
                request(week + 1, last);
            else
               deferred.resolve();
        });
    })(week, last);

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

**B- Load other stuff in the mean time**

```
function otherStuff() {
    // return some promise
}
```

**C- when A and B are done call `someFunction`**

```
var promises = []
promises.push(loadWeek(1, 10));
promises.push(otherStuff(...));
$.when.apply($, promises).done(someFunction);
```

Comment: You got the idea right. But don't think this will work because the first `loadWeek` promise will count as complete, and not the last.

Comment: what do you mean by the first and last ? this should pretty much work unless there is something in the problem i am not getting

Comment: @dabadaba loadWeek is only called once

Comment: no it is not, it's called recursively; and only the last call should be the signal that the process is done

Comment: double check the code .. the function `request` is called recursively .. not `loadWeek` .. `request` is the function defined inside `loadWeek`

Comment: oh yeah my bad, I am going to try it out then

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because I think it's the most elegant one. It also accidentaly suits my needs better because the "other" functions are only called sometimes so having them all in an array is more convenient and clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, but one of the simplest is to just make a small tweak to your attempt (see `***`):

```
function loadWeek(week, last, done) {      // ***
  $.get("week/" + i, function (response) {
    // do whatever with the response
    // make the request for the next week
    if (week + 1 <= last) {
      loadWeek(week + 1, last, done);      // ***
    } else {                               // ***
      done();                              // ***
    }                                      // ***
  });
}
```

then only push the *other* promises into `promises` (not the ones from `loadWeek` above), and:

```
loadWeek(1, lastWeek, function() {
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(someFunction);
});
```

Comment: I still don't see how that works with the need of having to wait for the other promises.

Comment: @dabadaba: Most of that code is yours. :-) When you call `loadWeek`, it makes **one** ajax call, and then waits for that to complete; when it completes, if there's still another week to load, it starts the next `loadWeek` call. We wait for that to complete, and so on; eventually, we're out of weeks to load, and so we call `done` (which is `someFunction` in my example call above). So there's only ever one ajax call in process, and `someFunction` (in that example) is called only when the last one completes.

Comment: Right. But that's not all. I mentioned this get tricky because not only the process of loading these matches asynchronously is involved, but there are also some additional AJAX calls that need to be waited on by `done`/`someFunction`. Here you're straight calling `done` after the last week is being loaded but that's not what I am after. Yes, I'm trying to call `done` after the last week is loaded, but **also** after all functions in the `promises` array have finished (I repeat, this array contains additional functions that have nothing to do with loading our matches)

Comment: @dabadaba: Just combine the approaches: Push only the promises that you need to wait for in the array, not the `loadWeek` ones, and then instead of calling `done` directly, so `$.when.apply($, promises).then(done);` (or do the equivalent in `someFunction`, which is what I'd probably do -- smaller pieces working together).

Comment: I think I understand now. But won't this approach mean that the functions in `promises` will only be called after the last week is loaded? I don't necessarily need that, but it doesn't hurt either I guess.

Comment: @dabadaba: No, it doesn't. The functions aren't in `promises`, just the promises they *return*. So if you've called the functions and pushed the promises they return into `promises`, the work of those functions is already underway. All the above does is wait for the last week to come back, and then wait for the promises in `promises` to be settled. (And it's fine if they already have been; `someFunction` will still get called.)

Answer (score 0):

You want a function that runs when a promise, and a function finishes. Small Workaround:

```
 var c=0;
 function callbyboth(){
 c++;
 if(c==2){
  //both executed
  //run your code
 }
 }
```

Add this on your promise

```
Promise.then(callbyboth);
```

And at the recursive function:

```
if(week+1>=last){
  callbyboth();
}else{
 //recursion
}
```

Comment: I don't understand completely what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: You said TJCrowders solution didnt work because you have more Promises and want all of them to finish. The upper code is a workaround, it simply counts how many times the function was called, so if you have two promises/callbacks to await, the function waits to be called two times